# Resta entre variables de distintas funciones

Tags: javascript, jquery

me gustaria saber como podria hacer una resta entre las variables totalprice y total price2 y mostrarla en el label Lbtot

Aqui mi codigo :

```
                 $(function() {
                     $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
                         var totalPrice = 0, ctlPrice;
                         $('.Gvcobranzas tr').each(function() {
                             if ($(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked")) {
                                 ctlPrice = $(this).find('[id$= Label3]');
                                 totalPrice += parseFloat(ctlPrice.text().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''));
                             }
                         });
                         $('.sum').text("$ " + totalPrice.toFixed(2));
                     });
                 });

                 $(function() {

                     $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
                         var totalPrice2 = 0, ctlPrice2;
                         $('.GvNotasCredito2 tr').each(function() {
                             if ($(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked")) {
                                 ctlPrice2 = $(this).find('[id$= Label20]');
                                 totalPrice2 += parseFloat(ctlPrice2.text().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''));
                             }
                         });
                         $('.res').text("$ " + totalPrice2.toFixed(2));
                     });
                 });

             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dos detalles:

- Cuando usas `$(function () { //mi codigo})` lo que estás haciendo es ejecutar el código cuando la página esté cargada y lista. con lo que lo ideal es que todo el código esté dentro de la misma función.
- De todo modos, el tener dos funciones, una para obtener cada valor, es una buena idea, pero lo ideal sería llamar a cada una y que éstas devolviesen el valor que calculan.

Si unes estas dos ideas puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$(function() {

    function getTotalPrice() {
        var totalPrice=0;
        $('.Gvcobranzas tr').each(function() {
            if ($(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked")) {
                var ctlPrice = $(this).find('[id$= Label3]');
                totalPrice += parseFloat(ctlPrice.text().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''));
            }
        });
        return totalPrice;
    }

    function getTotalPrice2() {
        var totalPrice2=0;
        $('.GvNotasCredito2 tr').each(function() {
            if ($(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked")) {
                var ctlPrice2 = $(this).find('[id$= Label20]');
                totalPrice2 += parseFloat(ctlPrice2.text().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''));
            }
        });
    }

    var totalPrice=getTotalPrice();
    var totalPrice2=getTotalPrice2();
    $('.sum').text("$ " + totalPrice.toFixed(2));
    $('.res').text("$ " + totalPrice2.toFixed(2));

    var difference=totalPrice - totalPrice2;
    $('#LbTot').text("$ "+difference.toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: Si quisiera en vez d emostrarlo en un label como podria hacerlo con un texbot? es igual?

Comment: Sí, prácticamente puedes añadir el texto en  cualquier elemento con ".text()" o ". val()"

Answer (score 0):

Encierra toda la logica en solo metodo anonimo. Luego las variables `totalPrice` y `totalPrice2` las declaras fuera de los eventos `change` para que ambos eventos puedan acceder las variables. Creas un boton que al darle clic, reste los 2 valores de las variables. Recuerda crear el evento dentro de la funcion anonima tambien para que pueda acceder las variables `totalPrice` y `totalPrice2`:

```
$(function() {

    var totalPrice = 0;
    var totalPrice2 = 0;

     $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
         var ctlPrice;
         totalPrice = 0;
         $('.Gvcobranzas tr').each(function() {
             if ($(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked")) {
                 ctlPrice = $(this).find('[id$= Label3]');
                 totalPrice += parseFloat(ctlPrice.text().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''));
             }
         });
         $('.sum').text("$ " + totalPrice.toFixed(2));
     });

     $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
        var ctlPrice2;
        totalPrice2 = 0;
         $('.GvNotasCredito2 tr').each(function() {
             if ($(this).find('input:checkbox').attr("checked")) {
                 ctlPrice2 = $(this).find('[id$= Label20]');
                 totalPrice2 += parseFloat(ctlPrice2.text().replace(/[^\d\.]/g, ''));
             }
         });
         $('.res').text("$ " + totalPrice2.toFixed(2));
     });

     $("#restar").click(function() {
         alert(totalPrice - totalPrice2);// imprimes la resta
     });

 });
```